# JSON formatting adding \ characters when I append file, but not to string in output

Tags: python, json, formatting, append, flickr

I am using the following function to get `json` from the flickr `API`.  The string it returns is a properly formatted chunk of JSON:

```
def get_photo_data(photo_id):
    para = {}
    para["photo_id"] = photo_id
    para["method"] = "flickr.photos.getInfo"
    para["format"] = "json"
    para["api_key"] = FLICKR_KEY
    request_data = params_unique_combination("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/", para)

    if request_data in CACHE_DICTION:
        return CACHE_DICTION[request_data]
    else:
        response = requests.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/", para)
        CACHE_DICTION[request_data] = response.text[14:-1]
        cache_file = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'w')
        cache_file.write(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))
        cache_file.close()
        return response.text[14:-1]
```

The issue I am having is that when I go to write the json to my cache file it keeps adding in backslashes, like this example:

`"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/format-json_method-flickr.photos.getInfo_photo_id-34869402493": "{\"photo\":{\"id\":\"34869402493\",\"secret\":\"56fcf0342c\",\"server\":\"4057\",\"farm\":5,\"dateuploaded\":\"1499030213\",\"isfavorite\":0,\"license\":\"0\",\"safety_level\":\"0\",\"rotation\":0,\"originalsecret\":\"c4d1d316ed\",\"originalformat\":\"jpg\",\"owner\":{\"nsid\":\"150544082@N05\",\"username\":\"ankitrana_\",\"realname\":\"Ankit Rana\",\"location\":\"Cincinnati, USA\",\"iconserver\":\"4236\",\"iconfarm\":5,\"path_alias\":\"ankitrana_\"},\"title\":{\"_content\":\"7\"},\"description\":{\"_content\":\"\"},\"visibility\":{\"ispublic\":1,\"isfriend\":0,\"isfamily\":0},\"dates\":{\"posted\":\"1499030213\",\"taken\":\"2017-06-19 13:43:38\",\"takengranularity\":\"0\",\"takenunknown\":\"0\",\"lastupdate\":\"1499041020\"},\"views\":\"41\",\"editability\":{\"cancomment\":0,\"canaddmeta\":0},\"publiceditability\":{\"cancomment\":1,\"canaddmeta\":0},\"usage\":{\"candownload\":1,\"canblog\":0,\"canprint\":0,\"canshare\":1},\"comments\":{\"_content\":\"0\"},\"notes\":{\"note\":[]},\"people\":{\"haspeople\":0},\"tags\":{\"tag\":[{\"id\":\"150538742-34869402493-5630\",\"author\":\"150544082@N05\",\"authorname\":\"ankitrana_\",\"raw\":\"cincinnati\",\"_content\":\"cincinnati\",\"machine_tag\":0},{\"id\":\"150538742-34869402493-226\",\"author\":\"150544082@N05\",\"authorname\":\"ankitrana_\",\"raw\":\"ohio\",\"_content\":\"ohio\",\"machine_tag\":false},
... etc., etc.}`

How can I store the JSON to the existing file without these additional `\` characters, as it is represented when I print the string?

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `your_string.decode('string_escape')` to unescape `\"` to `"`

update:

your string escaped because `json.dumps()`, it convert object to string and later you can read it using `json.loads()`, the result are unescaped.

you can save it without slash using `str()`

```
cache_file.write(str(CACHE_DICTION))
# {'myparam' :'"162000","photo":...'
```

but the problem it save to file with single quotes, it not valid json and not compatible with `json.loads()`

my suggestion keep your code as above, except you want to store it to file `CACHE_FNAME.json`

```
cache_file = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'w')
cache_file.write(response.text)
cache_file.close()
# {"photos":{"page":1,"pages":6478,..}
```

Comment: Could you give me a bit more on this?  When I try to create a string var with the response text and then use decode it tells me decode can not be used on a string.  I tried encoding the json as UTF-8 before dumping, but no luck with that either.  This seems like it could solve my issue, but I am still a newbie to programming, so I don't totally understand how to utilize it.

Comment: updated the answer, see above. `.decode('string_escape')` is not needed because slash came from `json.dumps()`

Comment: this is a confusing answer. Doing a json.dumps(str(CACHE_DICTION)) does not remove the backslashes in the outputted json

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the "\" with the str.replace function in python

Add the code after the following line

> cache_file = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'w')

```
json_item = str(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))
json_item.replace("\", "")
```

and change this line

> cache_file.write(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))

to

> cache_file.write(json_item)

let me know if this works for you

Comment: This does solve the issue, but I am concerned about circumstances where the json contains legitimate backslashes.

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks for pointing this out. It will probably help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

just replace `\` with a whitespace.
I did the same thing while i was working with JSON.

```
json_new = json.replace('\\', '')
```